# Is there a solution to this ? $f_0(n)=2n−1,\\ f_{k+1}(n)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_k(i)$

Tags: summation

after developing a formula, I came up against this :

$$f_0(n)=2n−1,\\
 f_{k+1}(n)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_k(i)$$

So, for example :$$f_1(n)= n^2\\
f_2(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ 
Can we find $f_n(n)$ ?

Thanks to Jens Renders for his advice of rewriting it in a more logical way

Comment: Just a notation advice: you are using $n$ as a variable, as the index of summation and as the last term of the sum at the same time. This is confusing, not to mention it does not make much sense.

Comment: $n$ can't be both a dumb variable in $\sum$ and the upper bound for this same variable.

Comment: I know, but I cannot see how I could chose a different index name. If I had chosen `i` for the index name, the second example wouldn't make any sence either

Comment: I do understand the question, and I understand why it is difficult to write down. I would write it like this: $f_0(n) = 2n-1$, $f_{k+1}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_k(i)$. You want to know what is $f_n(n)$ or maybe more generally $f_k(n)$ in closed form. If you agree, could you edit that in your question?

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2266856/399263, but you have to clarify your indexes, it is still vague what you want to sum. It looks like the question I linked, but this is just one interpretation.

Comment: If you mean what I wrote in my previous comment, you can check out the pattern [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSyzSUMpTyFTS5EpTsFUw0srUNeRKyy9SyFbIzFMoSsxLT9UwNNC04lIAgoKizLwSjTRNMAekvLg0VyNNRyFTR8FQRyFPU6-4NKlYozrPKrNWEwAaQxfq&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the [Hockey-Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) repeatedly gives
$$
f_1(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nf_0(k)=\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n+1}{2}
$$
$$
f_2(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nf_1(k)=\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+2}{3}
$$
$$
f_3(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nf_2(k)=\binom{n+2}{4}+\binom{n+3}{4}
$$
Following this pattern, we get
$$
f_k(n)=\binom{n+k-1}{k+1}+\binom{n+k}{k+1}
$$
Thus, setting $k=n$, we get
$$
f_n(n)=\binom{2n-1}{n+1}+\binom{2n}{n+1}
$$